# mappedBy to many values

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, mappedby

I have this error

> mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

I know what is the problem is that I should make the mappeby value "person" istead of person1 and person2 but the probleme is that I have 2 variable of type person (person1,person2) in class Contact I can't name them the same name !

in class Person

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person")
private Set<Contact> contact = new HashSet<>();
```

in class Contact

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_person", nullable = false)
private Person person1;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_person", nullable = false)
private Person person2;
```

my MCD :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GYxJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mappedBy` is used to denote the referencing side of an existing relationship, so you can't really map it to two relationships at the same time in JPA. You'll have to define `mappedBy` attribute separately for `person1` and `person2`. What you could do to get both values in one attribute would be to define a transient attribute and join them in the entity manually. Something like:

```java
@Entity
public class Person {
  // Other attributes

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = 
     "person1")
  private Set<Contact> contactOne = new HashSet<>();

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = 
    "person2")
  private Set<Contact> contactTwo = new HashSet<>();

  @Transient
  private Set<Contact> allContacts;

  public Person() {
    this.allContacts = new HashSet<>(contactOne);
    allContacts.addAll(contactTwo);
  }
}
```

But this is only for read-only access and you would have to keep the value synchronized with values of `contactOne` and `contactTwo`.